# Infinitescroll get first element after retrieve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll

I am using [Infinite scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) in my website. It is fine when i am scrolling down. But on a button click i am trying to get the data. So i have used :

```
nextpage = $('.selector').infinitescroll('retrieve');
```

Here my next page has been added. But i want the first element of the next page added. So i have tried to find the first element from the variable "nextpage" and get the first element from :

```
firstelement = nextpage['0'].firstElementChild.innerHTML
console.log(nextpage['0'].firstElementChild.innerHTML);
```

This is giving the first element but this is only text version not html dom so i am trying to find a image".imglazy" from the first element so i have tried below to get this.

```
 firstelement = firstelement.parseHTML();
 firstelement.find('.imglazy').attr('src');
```

But this is not working. Can anyone please help me to find the first element of next page? Is my process is wrong? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get html using jquery

```
var firstelement = $('.selector').children().find(':first-child').html();
```

and for image you can use

```
var imagefromfirstelement = $('.selector').children().find(':first-child .imglazy').attr('src');
```

hope it help

Comment: Thnx for your help. But it is showing this error "nextpage[0].children is not a function"

Comment: @Learner updated answer and like Happy Tutor said .. console.log(nextpage['0']);  it should output  [object Object]

Answer (score 2):

Try to log the result, you can get some result:

```
 console.log(nextpage);
```